# How to convert a continous time simulink model to discrete time model in Simulink?

Tags: simulink

For example, I have a controller consisting of integrator and sine web signal combined in the input. My question may be very naive to you, please help me to understand.
[In the picture I have a frequency which is the input of an integrator then two cos and sine block. How to make each Simulink block discrete using ZOH and rate transition block in Simulink.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHiKv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two potential solutions

- Change the sample time of the sinewave to something that is non-zero. This will make it a discrete signal
- Use a Zero Order Hold (as you've mentioned) to convert the signal to discrete, you will need to specify a sample time for this block to perform the conversion. Setting the time to 0.5 will sample the signal every half second for example.

Comment: Thank you for your information. What about the integrator, do I need to add three ZOH blocks or only 2 ZOH blocks after sine & cos will serve the purposes?

Comment: Add a single ZOH before or after the sin/cos/mux section